# Some items are missing to store in my android device using ORMLite library

Tags: android, ormlite

I want to store values from JSON in that some of the items are not stored in my local DB.  I'm using the ormlite library for Android.

Comment: post related code so that we can have a look

Comment: @ShalauddinAhamadShuza i Created a class with POJO with basic details like name,price,desc.. after gettting the data from the JSON ,i am converting this JSON to Object and storing in to my device. For storing im using ORM lite. im hitting and storing data in a goood maner . but some of the items are missing while storing (sync).. If i do full sync those are getting stored without any issues.

Comment: If you code properly then it must store. There is bug in your code